# Meterpreter error while using Metasploit framework to hack Android phones

Tags: linux

While using Metasploit framework in Kali Linux after the session gets opened I don't get the next step. Like `meterpreter>` does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

u can try: sessions command

```
msf exploit(handler) > sessions 

Active sessions
===============

  Id  Name  Type                        Information          Connection
  --  ----  ----                        -----------          ----------
  1         meterpreter dalvik/android  u0_a280 @ localhost  192.168.43.216:4545 -> 192.168.43.1:47450 (192.168.43.1)
```

you can select id numbers to use already opened sessions.

```
msf exploit(handler) > sessions -i 1
[*] Starting interaction with 1...

meterpreter > help
```